# Image making a div grow unnecessarily when added

Tags: css

I've got a wrapper div that's vertically and horizontally centered, and then two more divs inside it that are intended to share the space of the wrapper in a 50/50 split. When I add an image ('fireplace') to the topmost div ('wall'), even though the image should have no trouble fitting in the allocated space, the wall div is expanding its height vertically and ends up taking more than the intended amount of space in the wrapper. Here's the CSS code for the divs and the image in question:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 85vh;
  width: 85vw;
}

#container {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

#wall {
  background-color: darkred;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.fireplace {
  height: 20vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the height of the container and the wall to be 42.5vh (half of the wrapper size) seems to fix this behavior.